# How to reach UICollectionViewCell on ViewController

Tags: swift, casting, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionViewCell with 2 imageView in it. I create 8 from this Cell. I have a function called Flip which allows me to change the imageView. What I want to do is that when the game starts, all 8 of my cells are displayed (i.e. frontImageView) and then after 10 seconds they are all reversed. I couldn't reach CollectionViewCell from ViewController. I hope I was able to explain my problem.

This is my flip code on CollectionViewCell

```
func flip() {
        
        UIView.transition(from: frontImageView, to: backImageView, duration: 0.3, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft, .showHideTransitionViews], completion: nil)
        
    }
```

I tried putting static in front of imageviews.
I tried assigning the indexPath of cellForItemAt to a variable and using this variable to cast it as ColletcionViewCell, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume:

- you have a `UICollectionView` with the var name `collectionView`
- your collection view cell class is named `GameCell`
- `GameCell` has a public `flip()` function

You can do this:

```
    let cells = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
    cells.forEach { idxPath in
        if let c = collectionView.cellForItem(at: idxPath) as? GameCell {
            c.flip()
        }
    }
```